# node crypto key derivation from a password produces different results with browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, browserify, node-crypto

I'm trying to re-create [Symfony's `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder`](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.html) in the browser.

I have some issue with browserify and crypto module.
I try to generate hash with JavaScript but without Node.

Here is my code with node:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var encodePassword = function (raw, salt) {
    var salted = raw + '{'+salt+'}',
        hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(salted, 'utf-8');

    for (var i = 1; i < 5000 ; i++) {
        hash = crypto.createHash('sha512').update(hash.digest('binary')+salted);
    }

    return hash.digest('base64');
};

console.log(encodePassword("admin", "81b6zjhf64w8kogsgkgw804ss8gc0w0"));
```

It returns:

```
qmNs3bqtTeoS4uRq2Chh1fUNPu+lzn3KR7mWFHAq5NEPrK0QZ9XkLDUniZ39uosnozNrPL7mByzUZ/A19Io4sQ==
```

Now, considering I need to implement this without node, I used browserify

```
browserify index.js > crypto.js
```

I created a test page and include:

```
<script src="crypto.js"></script>
```

The console log output is:

```
JtDIZwGDybG6tG7PE2SeXS0BEa4vOoxpu3y7Il6P6OQL9djmrk5S0vjTGoQowGO22OvQ58tC05eZBt/yvyJv+A==
```

Any idea about why I have two different results?

Otherwise, is there a way to obtains the same result in pure JS (without node)?

Comment: You could start using some standardized scheme such as PBKDF2 instead of rolling your own. I suspect the issue has something to do with the `'binary'` in `hash.digest('binary')`. Anyway, SJCL provides a fast PBKDF2 implementation as well as node.js' crypo module.

Comment: Thank you but I'm trying to reproduce the way [Symfony encrypts password](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.html). Therefore, I can't use PBKDF2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the trouble with the browserified code is, but the following is a CryptoJS implementation of [Symfonys `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/MessageDigestPasswordEncoder.php).

```js
/**
 * Encodes a password according to Symfonys MessageDigestPasswordEncoder
 * @param password String
 * @param salt String
 * @param base64 Boolean (default: false) If false, then the result is Hex-encoded
 * @param hasher Optional Hasher (default: CryptoJS.algo.SHA512)
 * @param iterations Optional Integer (default: 5000)
 * @returns {String} Iterated and salted hash of a password
 */
function encodePassword(password, salt, base64, hasher, iterations) {
  hasher = hasher || CryptoJS.algo.SHA512;
  iterations = iterations || 5000;
  hasher = hasher.create();
  salt = password + "{" + salt + "}";
  var digest = hasher.finalize(salt);
  for (var i = 1; i < iterations; i++) {
    hasher.reset();
    hasher.update(digest);
    digest = hasher.finalize(salt);
  }
  if (base64) {
    return digest.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); // Base64-encoded string
  }
  return digest.toString(); // Hex-encoded string
}

output.innerHTML = encodePassword("admin", "81b6zjhf64w8kogsgkgw804ss8gc0w0", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha512.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```